# In Tampermonkey, why does @require work for some scripts but not others

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a userscript using TamperMonkey on Chrome.

I want to use https://github.com/Fil/d3-geo-voronoi so I put this in my script header:

```
// @require        https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7.0.0/dist/d3.min.js
// @require        https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-delaunay@6.0.2/dist/d3-delaunay.min.js
// @require        https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-geo-voronoi@1.6.0/dist/d3-geo-voronoi.min.js
```

d3 and d3-delaunay are imported correctly but for some reason, d3-geo-voronoi is not. I can see in the chrome dev tools sources tab that tampermonkey has included all three scripts but the Chrome dev tools console shows that `d3` and `d3.Delaunay` are defined but `d3.geoVoronoi` is not.

If I copy and paste the contents of https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-geo-voronoi@1.6.0/dist/d3-geo-voronoi.min.js into the console, `d3.geoVoronoi` is defined and works as I would expect.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SweetAlert in Tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946942/sweetalert-in-tampermonkey)